Natural roots of multivariate integer polynomials
I know the problem of determining whether a multivariate integer polynomial has integer roots is in general undecidable. However, does this change when we consider only its natural roots?

The two problems are equivalent, by the following slightly funny pair of tricks. It suffices to write down two algorithms:

An algorithm which given a polynomial $f$ with integer coefficients produces a polynomial $f'$ with integer coefficients such that $f = 0$ has an integer solution iff $f'$ has a natural solution.
In the other direction, an algorithm which given a polynomial $g$ with integer coefficients produces a polynomial $g''$ with integer coefficients such that $g = 0$ has a natural solution iff $g''$ has an integer solution.

This can be done by taking
$$f'(x_1, \dots x_n) = \prod_{\text{signs}} f(\pm x_1, \dots \pm x_n)$$
where the product is over all $2^n$ possible choices of signs, and
$$g''(y_{k, i}, 1 \le k \le 4, 1 \le i \le n) = g \left( \sum_{i=1}^4 y_{1, i}^2, \dots \sum_{i=1}^4 y_{n, i}^2 \right)$$
where here we've used Lagrange's four-square theorem.
